# Windows Service is not installing via Setup project

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation, setup-project

I have a windows service and a setup project to go along with it. When I run the setup project install command it gets part way through the install and then gives me an 1001 error saying it could not find the testservice.exe.config file.

I looked in my source project and that file is never generated... I have the .exe one but none of them are .exe.config files. How can I generate this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change your users.config file to App.config.  After that Visual Studio should do the rest.

Comment: That's what it was! Why does it have to be called App.config... SHould be able to name it anything

Answer (score 3):

You certainly have App.config file. If you compile your service, there should be testservice.exe.config generated in Bin folder. Read [When is an app.config created, when an app.exe.config and what is the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173283/when-is-an-app-config-created-when-an-app-exe-config-and-what-is-the-difference) for further clarification.

Comment: I have a config file I named users.config but when I compile my app it isn't copied and renamed xxxx.exe.config.