# Some of the properties of EventSchemaTraceListener are not recognised app.config

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

The following properties of EventSchemaTraceListener that are intended for log rotation are not recognised in app.config (.Net 3.5):

```
bufferSize="65536"
maximumFileSize="1024"
logRetentionOption="LimitedCircularFiles"
maximumNumberOfFiles="2"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you say that the properties aren't recognized in `app.config`; make sure that you're also updating the `[ApplicationName].exe.config` file located in the output folder with your executable (or deleting it so it can be created again from scratch when you run the application).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174232/180043) for an explanation of why you can't just update `app.config` to see your new settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the attributes are flagged as errors (which might just be an IDE problem) or do the settings not work?

There's an example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventschematracelistener.aspx

Note, though, that some of the comments suggest that they also had issues getting it to work.