# Is Web.Config the same as app.exe.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, app-config

I am attempting to run a .Net 2 app on a .Net 4 app pool. [According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx) I should add a few lines of code to my app.exe.config file. There is no such file currently but there is a Web.config file. Microsoft says:

> To add a configuration file, on the Visual Studio menu bar, choose
>   Project, Add New Item. Choose General from the left pane, and then
>   choose Configuration File. Name the configuration file
>   appName.exe.config. These menu choices are not available for Windows
>   Store app or Windows phone app projects, because you cannot change the
>   activation policy on those platforms.

But in Visual Studio 2017 there is no such option. I tried adding the lines of code to web.config but it did not fix the problem

```
<startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>

</startup>
```

Should I create an app.exe.config file manually using a txt file?

Comment: `web.config` is for web applications (ASP.NET), while `app.config` is for Windows Forms, WPF and console applications

Comment: More info @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173283/when-is-an-app-config-created-when-an-app-exe-config-and-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Since its web application you don't need to add app.exe.config. If you add error details you are facing then someone can help you.

Comment: Looks like this was somewhat answered before on SO here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412552/differences-between-app-config-and-web-config